# Get Items from map and add to a vector c++

Tags: c++

I rote this code in my program

```
JSONNode::const_iterator iter = root.begin();
    for (; iter!=root.end(); ++iter)
    {
        const JSONNode& arrayNode = *iter;
        std::string type = arrayNode["type"].as_string();
        if(type == "node")
        {
            std::string id = arrayNode["id"].as_string();
            double lat = arrayNode["lat"].as_float();
            double lon = arrayNode["lon"].as_float();
            Node node;
            node.SetId(id);
            node.SetLatitude(lat);
            node.SetLongitude(lon);
            nodesMap.insert( std::pair<std::string, Node>(id, node) );
        }
        else if(type == "way")
        {
            std::string wayId = arrayNode["id"].as_string();
            wayNode.SetId(wayId);
            std::vector<Node> collection;
            const JSONNode& wayNodes = arrayNode["nodes"];
            const JSONNode& nodes = wayNodes.as_array();
            JSONNode::const_iterator WayIter = nodes.begin();
            for (; WayIter!=nodes.end(); ++WayIter)
            {
                const JSONNode& arrayNode = *WayIter;
                std::string id = arrayNode.as_string();
                if(nodesMap.find(id) != nodesMap.end())
                {
                    collection.push_back(nodesMap.find(id)->second);
                    nodesMap.erase(id);  
                }
            }
            wayNode.SetNodesCollection(collection);
            std::cout<<"Item Id ->>>>>>>>>>>>>" << collection[2].GetId() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Node.h

```
class Node {
private:
    std::string id;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
public:
    Node();
    Node(const Node& orig);
    Node(std::string id, double lat, double lon);
    virtual ~Node();
    void SetLongitude(double longitude);
    double const & GetLongitude() const;
    void SetLatitude(double latitude);
    double const & GetLatitude() const;
    void SetId(std::string id);
    std::string const & GetId() const;
};
```

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node() {
}
Node::Node(const Node& orig) {
}
Node::~Node() {
}
Node::Node(std::string id, double lat, double lon){
    this->id = id;
    this->latitude = lat;
    this->longitude = lon;
}
void Node::SetLongitude(double longitude) {
    this->longitude = longitude;
}
double const & Node::GetLongitude() const {
    return longitude;
}
void Node::SetLatitude(double latitude) {
    this->latitude = latitude;
}
double const & Node::GetLatitude() const {
    return latitude;
}
void Node::SetId(std::string id) {
    this->id = id;
}
std::string const & Node::GetId() const {
    return id;
}
```

but when i try to ptint id of second item std::cout<<"Item Id ->>>>>>>>>>>>>" << collection[2].GetId() << std::endl;
it gets a blank value. but size of the collection is 82, get the correct value for the collection size.

i need some help to sort out this.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node::Node(const Node& orig) {
    this->id = orig.id;
    this->latitude = orig.latitude;
    this->longitude = orig.longitude;
}
```

Modify your copy constructor as this.

Comment: Why not use the implicitly defined copy constructor instead of defining a new one? And if defining a new one, why not use initialization lists?

Comment: @jogojapan I concur. It would be the simplest thing to do. Fixing something by *deleting* code isn't entirely common, and embracing it should be celebrated =)